# Using spatie Laravel-activitylog to track user logs only though apis and made in specific time

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, vue.js

I'm working on a project using Spatie Laravel-activitylog Package to keep track of user logs for different activities in the project. Currently everything is being logged correctly.
I would track different events including update, create, delete in different models within a specific time and only events through the api, i'm thinking of using a middleware but i'm stuck on how to approach it.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't test it but I guess it can help you:

```
php artisan make:middleware LogApiActivity
```

Define the Middleware Logic:

In the middleware, you can check if the request is an API request and then log the activity accordingly. Assuming you have a UserActivity model for logging activities:

// app/Http/Middleware/LogApiActivity.php

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Spatie\Activitylog\Models\Activity;

class LogApiActivity
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);

        if ($request->is('api/*') && Auth::check()) {
            $user = Auth::user();
            $activityDescription = $this->getActivityDescription($request);

            // Log the activity
            activity()
                ->performedOn($user) // You can change this to the model you are working with
                ->withProperties(['description' => $activityDescription])
                ->log('api_action');
        }

        return $response;
    }

    private function getActivityDescription($request)
    {
        // You can customize this based on your needs
        return $request->method() . ' ' . $request->path();
    }
}
```

Register the Middleware:

Add the middleware to the appropriate group in Kernel.php:

// app/Http/Kernel.php

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        // ...
    ],

    'api' => [
        // ...
        \App\Http\Middleware\LogApiActivity::class,
    ],
];
```

Make sure it's placed after any middleware that modifies the request or response.

Configure Activity Log Model:

In your Activity model, make sure you've configured it to use the correct subject_id and causer_id columns in your database.

// app/Models/UserActivity.php

```
use Spatie\Activitylog\Models\Activity as SpatieActivity;

class UserActivity extends SpatieActivity
{
    protected $table = 'activity_log';

    // Customize other properties if needed
}
```

Don't forget to update your config/activitylog.php configuration file accordingly.

With this setup, any API request made by an authenticated user will log an activity. Adjust the logic based on the specific events you want to log and the models you want to associate the activities with.

Comment: Thanks for yor quick response, i had the same approach though abit modified but abit different, my issue is obtaining the model from the middleware, i already figured out the description, changes, causer. 
If there is a way to get the model from the middleware it will be very helpful

Comment: @princeallan For the model maybe you can add a key in your routes, for example having a group of routes with {modelKey} as a prefix, then get the key in the middleware and map the key to a model or send the model inside of the request then get it in the middleware, ('model_key' => 'path/to/model/modelName')
I think we have just these 2 ways :)

Comment: I finally figured a work around. I added the model to the request in the respective controller
``` $request->attributes->add(['model' => User::class]) ```